# Request method 'GET' not supported Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, jstl

I have the following code in the controller

```
  private static final String CJOB_MODEL    = "cJobNms";

  @RequestMapping(value = MAIN_VIEW, method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String showTestXsd(//@ModelAttribute(FORM_MODEL) TestXsdForm xsdForm,
            //@ModelAttribute(MODEL) @Valid
            //TestXsdTable testXsdTable,
            @RequestParam String selected,
            Model model) throws DataException {

        String cJobNm =null;
        List<String> cJobNmList = null;
        System.out.println("selected:"+ selected);
        String xsdView = testXsdService.getXsdString();
        cJobNmList = testXsdService.getCJobNm();
        Set<String> cJobNmSet = new HashSet<String>(cJobNmList);
        TestXsdForm xsdForm = new TestXsdForm();
        model.addAttribute("xsdView", xsdView);
        model.addAttribute("xsdFormModel", xsdForm);
        model.addAttribute(CJOB_MODEL, cJobNmSet);
        xsdForm.setXsdString(xsdView);

        return MAIN_VIEW;
    }
```

And the following code in my jsp.

```
<form:form modelAttribute="testXsdTable" name="xsdForm" action="/xsdtest/testXsdTables"
                        id="xsdForm" method="POST" class="form"
                                            enctype="multipart/form-data" >


            <tr>
             <td>
              <label for="cJobs" class="fieldlabel">Jobs:</label>
               <select id="cJobs" name="cJobs" >
                <option value="${selected}" selected>${selected}</option>
                <c:forEach items="${cJobNms}" var="table">
                    <c:if test="${table != selected}">
                            <option value="${table}">${table}</option>
                        </c:if>
                 </c:forEach>
               </select>
            </td>
            </tr>
            <pre>
               <c:out value="${xsdForm.xsdString}"/>
            </pre>
<div class="confirmbuttons">
    <a href="#"class="button positive" id="saveXsdButton" onclick="saveTestXsd();">
        <span class="confirm">Save</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

When the user selects an option from the cJobNms list the selected value should be displayed in the controller method showTestXsd.  Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Currently I am getting a message : **Request method 'GET' not supported**

```
 @RequestMapping(value = SAVE_VIEW, method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveTestXsd( @ModelAttribute(MODEL) @Valid
                            TestXsdTable testXsdTable,
                            final BindingResult result,
                            final Principal principal,
                            Model model) throws DataException {

    boolean isNew = true;
    System.out.println("entering saveTestXsd in controller");
    Map<String,Object> modelMap = model.asMap();
    String xsdView = (String)modelMap.get("xsdView");
    System.out.println("xsdView:::"+ xsdView);
    if(testXsdTable!= null){
         System.out.println("xsdView(testXsdForm):::"+ testXsdTable.getXsdView());
    }


    // Check for validation errors
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return SAVE_VIEW;
    }

    // Get the user information
    User loggedInUser = (User) ((Authentication) principal)
                        .getPrincipal();

    return SAVE_VIEW;
}
```

Comment: Sorry for posting so much code so that people will get an idea about the problem, I have pasted it, and I am in the process of learning Spring MVC.  Hope the people in this site don't find it a problem in posting this much code.  Apologise if that is the case.....

Comment: What I mean by my comment in the post is that the job dropdown is currently displayed and when I select a value, I want the selected value to be available in the controller method to print.

Comment: Please show the javascript for `saveTestXsd()`. Also, you can edit your question to add more details.

Comment: I had an onchange method for this but I took out this call from the form.  I was able to alert that selected value but I was not sure how to get that value in the controller.  I had these two lines in the Js.

Comment: var data = $('#cJobs').serialize();                                       postForm('testXsdTables', $('#testXsdTables'), data);

Comment: Edit your question and add the full code to `saveTestXsd()`. You are submitting the form but also sending a get request which you shouldn't be.

Comment: so the user will select an option and based on the selected option will make a DB call to retrieve data and display it, the save will come later after the content is displayed.  so currently I don't have much code in saveTestXsd().  But I can put it.

Comment: A `<a>` element is like a link, it sends a GET. Before sending the get, because of your `postForm`, you are sending a POST which is handled by your `@RequestMapping` but you never see the response because it is hidden in the ajax call. The `<a>` click goes through and tries to do a GET to the current URL which is unsupported apparently. Try to add a `return false;` at the end of your javascript for the `saveTestXsd()`.

Comment: Currently it complains about the RequestParam selected.  It says that this paramater is not present.  should I include it as a hidden parameter

Comment: I've lost track of where you are. Please edit your answer putting all the details of the current state.

Comment: Currently the code in the jsp is the same as what I have posted.  The controller method showTestXsd has the following @RequestMapping @RequestMapping(value = MAIN_VIEW, method = RequestMethod.GET).  The JSP has no change and the saveTestXsd has no change.  Currently when I run it.  I get the following error "An application error has occured
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required S
tring parameter 'selected' is not present"

Comment: By the way thanks for your help, it provides me a great learning opportunity.

Comment: Dear user2684404, welcome to StackOverflow. There is really no need to delete this question. On StackOverflow we prefer to keep questions that has been answered so that others might be able to learn something from them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm going to start an answer and add to it as details become available. For your current error

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'selected' is not present
```

This happens because when you have something like

```
@RequestParam String selected,
```

And `@RequestParam` doesn't have a `value` attribute set, Spring will use the name of the parameter to look for the request parameter to bind. In your form, you obviously don't have a parameter named `selected`.  What you want is to get the value in

```
<select id="cJobs" name="cJobs" >
```

So change your `@RequestParam` to

```
@RequestParam(value = "cJobs") String selected
```

to match the `name` attribute of the `select` input element.

Comment: So I did add that, and I did define the "cJobs" in the form, but when I do this it says that String parameter'cJobs' is not present.

Comment: What do you mean _define the "cJobs" in the form_? It was already there. Also, this means you aren't submitting your form correctly. How are you doing that?

Comment: Yes what I meant was that it is already there, I had defined it earlier when I wrote the form.  Another thing to clarify is that I am stuck at the first stage, I am not clicking any submit button.  The idea is that a page comes up with drop down and I select a value which fetches data from DB and displays it.  The second stage is that of submission which call the saveTestXsd() method.

Comment: When I go the url I get an application error with the error stating that the parameter 'cJobs' is not present.

Comment: The spring exception I get is MissingServletRequestParameterException.

Comment: @user2684404 You say _The idea is that a page comes up_ Do you do a GET to retrieve this form? Which handler method should be handling it?

Comment: yes I do a GET to retrieve this form.  the handler method for that is the showTestXsd()

Comment: @user2684404 Then you don't need any request parameters. Remove it.

Comment: so Just to make it clear, I have some data in DB that I retreive and show in the form.  to retrieve and show the jsp form that I posted is used and the controller method for that is showTestXsd, hence you see the method is RequestMethod.GET.  After the data is displayed upon a selection from a dropdown.  I have a submit button in the page.  When clicked will do a POST request to the controller and will call the saveTestXsd method which has RequestMethod.POST in its RequestMapping annotation.

Comment: @user2684404 Yes, use a GET which should be handled by `showTestXsd()`. The method will render an HTML form with the values from your database and send that as a response. In your client (browser), you select a value from a drop down. You then submit the form (jaavscript or submit button) and that sends a POST which should be handled by `saveTestXsd()`. That's where you possibly want your selected value request parameter.

Comment: If I remove this the form will come up, but my intention is to access the selected value from the dropdown in the controller.  How would I do it.  I need that to pull the necessary data based on that selection from DB in order to display the data below the dropdown.

Comment: when I say access it in the controller.  I need the selected value in the showTestXsd in order to send that to DB to retrieve the data.  So how do I print the value of the selected dropdown value in the showTestXsd method.

Comment: @user2684404 You're misunderstanding the flow. In `showTestXsd` the value has yet to be selected. `showTestXsd()` simply populates the table.

Comment: Ok no that is not what I was looking for.  My intention is that a dropdown is displayed in the page.  Now when they select a value from the dropdown that goes and call the method showTestXsd which uses this value to fetch data and uses the same form to display it.  When they hit submit button then it will hit saveTestXsd to post the form. Where am I going wrong to achieve this approach.

Comment: @user2684404 I would use 3 methods, 1 for showing the form and dropdown, another (accessed through ajax) to show the selected value's data and a third to handle the form submit. If you want to use only your two. You can use `@RequestParam` with the `required` attribute set to false. If there is no request parameter, it will set your parameter to `null`. You can then check it for `null` and handle it accordingly.

Comment: how would you do with 3 methods.  I don't understand.  Because say we have showTestXsd which is only responsible for showing the dropdown.  So are you saying that it won't have any RequestMethod in its mapping.  And the intermediary second method will have GET and then use the RequestParam to get the value of selected and use that to retrieve the data and display it.  Won't Spring complain that it will find 2 methods with requestMethod GET.

Comment: @user2684404 You can just change the `RequestMapping` value attribute to some other path. It will handle just getting the data for the selected value and returning it, possibly as JSON, which your javascript can use to populate some `div`.

Comment: So I understand that approach so here it is not a table data.  I would have to put this ajax call to fetch the data but intermediary there is a service layer which builds a xml format out of the table data, and have to display this data upon selection of a dropdown element.  How would I do it....

Comment: Another thing I wanted to make it clear was that the service to DB layer I have it covered. There is a method in the service layer which takes in the primary key element fetches the data builds an XSD.  What I wanted to tie up was that, have that key value display in the drop down so that whenever user selects a value, it will pass that value to the service layer to fetch it and display the xsd data.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
@RequestMapping(value = MAIN_VIEW, method = RequestMethod.POST)
```

with

```
@RequestMapping(value = MAIN_VIEW, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

You should also consider changing the form POST method. Your use case is more of Get rather than POST

Comment: I changed the method in the form from method="POST" to method="GET" also changed it in the showTestXsd RequestMapping.  It complains that the string parameter 'selected' is not present.

Comment: This change on its own is not enough as OP is using javascript `postForm` to post the form. IT has nothing to do with the `method="post"` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

use the next code

```
@RequestMapping(value = MAIN_VIEW, method = RequestMethod.GET)
//if you want to use both ( post and get ) remove Request Method annotation

//@RequestMapping(value = MAIN_VIEW)
@RequestParam(value="cJobs", required = false) String selected; 
//use this to handle an optional parameter
```

Answer (score -3):

You just have make a change in `@RequestParam` which you have used in your code like

```
@RequestParam("studentName") String name
```

Replace above line of code with

```
@RequestParam(value="studentName") String name
```

Your problem will definitely be resolved.

Comment: We can abbreviate this annotation somewhat. When an annotation has a single member and that member is named “value”, you are allowed (and encouraged) to omit the “value=” in the annotation.
https://learning.oreilly.com/library/view/java-in-a/0596007736/ch04s03.html